# sqlite icu load collation in Wt

Tags: sqlite, wt

I am trying to use sqlite(3) icu_load_collation on Wt. (Wt 3.3.3 on ubuntu).
I have added

```
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION 1
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA 1
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_ICU 1
```

lines to sqlite3.h (srd/Wt/Dbo/backed/amalgamation/sqlite3.h) file and run make and sudo make install on build. It supposed to work, but it did not.
Compiler gives an error saying there is no function as "icu_load_collation" where I implemented.
In summary, I am trying to use "icu_load_collation" on Wt, but failed so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed. It seems sqlite3.c (std/Wt/Dbo/backend/amalgamation/sqlite3.c) file does not include sqlite3.h file. As a result of this "make" command does not detect any change and cannot make necessary .o file.
The solution is to write those lines (prewritten) into sqlite3.c file.

Have a nice day!